# Compiling and running cross-platform test environment

Tags: windows, linux, cross-platform, cross-compiling, virtualbox

Test environment: Linux and Windows.

I want to test my application to see if it will run cross-platform on Linux and Windows.

Currently I am running Linux Fedora 15 natively on my netbook. However, I have to test on a Windows machine. I tried installing Windows 7 Starter on my netbook using VirtualBox. However, my netbook is a `HP 210 Netbook with 2GB DDR3 RAM Atom N550 dual core 4 threads`. It is not powerful enough run virtual box; it is just too slow. This netbook is all I have. I am not sure if VMware Server will be much better than VirtualBox.

I am just wondering if there is anything else I can do to test a cross-platform application. I don't want to have to install Windows natively, then have to restart in Windows just to test.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine is fairly light weight and will allow you to setup for just your app. You can also include missing dll's if need be. The trick however is compiling natively for windows. I guess you could install a compiler under Wine as well. http://www.winehq.org/ Fedora should have a package ready to easily install.

Comment: I have wine installed already. However, some windows applications just don't install on wine correctly. However, I am willing to give it a try. What windows compiler would you recommend I install using wine? I was thinking about borland, but I think that might not install using wine.

Comment: @ant2009 Probably gnu32 is a safe bet and I seen some documentation in wine on installing.

Comment: @ant2009 Theres also the topic of cross compiling natively, but thats out of my scope. Basically rather than running a compiler in Wine, you run a compiler natively on linux and cross compile for windows. Maybe start here: mingw32 [link](http://www.mingw.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at all of the suggestions.